# Google Cloud Function Error "Function failed on loading user code." with Typescript Functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When I first create a Google Cloud Function with Typescript I run into the error
`Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Provided code is not a loadable module. Could not load the function, shutting down.`

In my package.json I have specified the main property as `"./build/app.js"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you don't specify a `.gcloudignore` file. The gcloud SDK tries to help, and supply one for you. 
The very end of that file has this line:
`#!include:.gitignore`
Which I was ignoring because it looks like a comment line. Bad idea on my part. While it strikes me as a violation of the principle of least astonishment it turns out if you read the top of the auto-generated file, it points out that the
`#!include:`
syntax includes the contents of the specified file in the `.gitcloudignore` file. Since I don't want my `build` folder added to git that means it also doesn't get uploaded to my function. Easy enough to fix, once the rabbit-holes are exited. Just delete that line from the auto-generated `.gcloudignore` file.